# Log rotation in Linux

Tags: logs, logrotate

Whenever I execute `ls` command in `/var/log` directory, I could find log files, e.g. `messages`, and their rotated versions, e.g. `messages.1.gz`.

Even though I am not using any utility like `logrotate`, how are these files being rotated automatically? What is the criteria (e.g. log file should reach 'X' MB or it is rotated every 'N' days) for the file to be rotated? And how can I control (enable/disable) log rotation?

**Note:** I have written a bash script, that would run on 1st day of every month. This script would compress the log file, copy the compressed file to a remote server and empty the original log file (so that newer logs are available on the next run). So, I do not want the log file to be rotated.

Comment: What makes you think you aren't using `logrotate`? Most distributions set it up as a default. What distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using RHEL 6.5. There is no configuration set in `/etc/logrotate.conf` for that particular log file.

Comment: Ignore, the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file, are there any files in the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory like my answer asked?

Comment: There are some files in the mentioned directory, but they do not include the log file under consideration.

Comment: Did you check the all the files for the 'file under consideration' one file in logrotate.d directory can have multiple files specified. The `messages` log would rotate inside this file: `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog`. I updated my answer with this information.

Comment: I could not find the filename in any of the files.

Answer (score 3):

Check if there are any files here: `/etc/logrotate.d`

If so, remove whichever relate to what you don't want to rotate. But be careful on what you are removing, make sure that you have a file-cleanup method for all files that are rotated with logrotate otherwise you run the risk of waking up one day and not understanding how your filesystem ran out of diskspace.

**Update**

Multiple files can be specified within a single file in the `logrotate.d` directory, an example is the `syslog` file. This also happens to be where the `messages` log you mentioned would be targeted.

`/etc/logrotate.d/syslog`

```
/var/log/messages 
/var/log/secure 
/var/log/maillog /var/log/spooler /var/log/boot.log /var/log/cron {
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

**Update #2**

Run this command to see if what is rotating your log files is syslog instead of logrotate:

```
grep -rni "message" /etc/cron.*/*
```

On Debian flavored systems, the syslog rotation can be controlled by a cron daily script which is normally located in `/etc/cron.daily/sysklogd`. My grep command should help identify if this is true in your case, (even though you are on RHEL).

More information can be found here: http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/06/rotating-linux-log-files-part-1-syslog/

Also check: `grep -rni "message" /etc/rsyslog.d/*`